# How to properly send file through selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I work with selenium 3.141.0 and chromewebdriver 83.0.4103 .
All the selenium libraries are proprerly imported and my script is working fine until i got this error.
I'm currently trying to upload a json file to an input :

```
<input type="file" class="file" id="ext-gen1563">
```

```
upload = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="file"]')
upload.send_keys("‪C:\\absolutepathtofile.json")
```

I'm getting the same error all the time :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument:
```

I tried to click on the "Choose File" button on the form and it's working well untill I need to pass the desired file, I understood that it's not the good way to do it so I worked on the input way.
I cannot test with the geckodriver or edge drive cause my organisation do not allow me to us them.

Here is the complete code of the element :

```
<div class="uploader"><div class="import-file-form"><input type="file" class="file" id="ext-gen1563"></div><div class="filename">No file chosen.</div><div class="clickable btn" id="ext-gen1564">Choose File</div></div>
```

Can you give me some nudges to solve this problem ?
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dealt with the same issue myself recently and it's possible that the solution I found for the website I was dealing with might work for yours.

I first identified the box where the file name ends up after you choose your file. This box never shows the full file path nor can you type in it as a human in the browser. Once I did this, I simply sent the keys of the full path to the file to this box... and it worked.

I was then able to just identify the 'submit' button and click it.

Here is the code I used but you will obviously have to identify the elements of your website.

The CSV variable is simply a CSV file I'm passing in.

```
ChooseFile = browser.find_element_by_name('files[field_import_file_und_0]')
import os
ChooseFile.send_keys(os.path.abspath(CSV))
Upload = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input[2]')
Upload.click()
Submit = browser.find_element_by_name('op')
Submit.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def base(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        return render(request, 'base.html')
    else:
        title = request. POST.get('title')
        file = request.POST.get('file')
        data = models.base(title=title,file=file)
        data.save()
        return render(request,'base.html')
```